# How to find a relation between the radii and the diameter?

Tags: geometry

In a cylindrical container with diameter d, there are 2 touching spheres with radii a and b. Both spheres touch top surface and the coat of the cylinder. The biggest ball also touches the base of the cylinder. Prove that √d = √a + √b.

[image that was added to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1JNv.png)

This is a problem from the VWO final 2019 (https://www.vwo.be/vwo/files/finalevwo2019.pdf (Dutch)). 
Since the competition, I have tried to solve this problem multiple times without succesn and I would like a hint as for where to start

things I tried:

-tried to reduce the problem to a 2d problem with both front view and top view. Failed because the circles (spheres in 2d view) would overlap in both views.

-tried to use the pythagorean theorem with the point of tangency of the two spheres, a length of (a-b) (as can be derived from the picture) and an unknown length, which can be projected on the top. Failed because the last length was unknown and can't be linked to a, b or d.

I would very much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pythagoras on triangle ABC with sides $u,v,w$:

[image]

$u,v,$ and $w$ can all be expressed in terms of $a,b,$ and $d$. Now just rearrange the identity $u^2=v^2+w^2$ and take the square root.

(The base of the  cylinder plays no role, and I wonder why they mentioned it.)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it. So i have thought of this aswell, the problem i had with this approach is that you don't know for sure the point of tangency of the two spheres lies in the given plane. if this isn't for sure, the circles would overlap and the solution wouldn't work. On the other hand, this situation does in fact lead to the solution, so I would assume this is the correct way of reasoning.

Comment: You just have to choose the vertical plane that contains the centres of both circles.

Comment: oh yeah, the base does play a role in the fact that w= height-b, but the height isn't given. You can derive that the height is 2a from the information that the biggest sphere touches both sides.

Comment: But you don't need the height. Look at the diagram.

Comment: ah yes indeed, it's just a-b. silly me. thanks for the help, again.